# Is there a fast way to find records that were created OR updated within a date range?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have to run a query where I need to find all records that were created OR updated within a date range.

The problem with this is that the data set is large and so a query in the past couple years can return a few million rows.

I think there are a couple problems here.

MySQL isn't going to be able to choose a key/index since it's doing created_at > X OR updated_at > X, so it's going to be slow. How can I speed this up?

Comment: Additionally, if you can provide us with the query execution plan so that we can pin point exactly the culprit, but I believe that a secondary index on the table is a very nice start.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Are these two columns nullable?

Comment: And why not use just `WHERE updated_at > X`? Surely a row cannot be updated before it is created, can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OR` is a difficult to optimize.  'Often' the fix is to rewrite using `UNION`.

```
( SELECT ... WHERE created_at > X )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... WHERE updated_at > X )
```

and have 2 separate indexes:

```
INDEX(created_at)
INDEX(updated_at)
```

Each `SELECT` will pick its optimal index.  The `UNION`, alas, will involve a tmp table and a dedupping pass.  Therefore, there are cases where a full table scan using `OR` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I usually implement updated to be set to the creation date on creation.  It makes queries like this trivial as you only need to query on the update date.

Using triggers for both ensures they are correctly maintained.

On insert:
    created, updated = NOW

On update:
    created = old.created (prevents modification)
    update = NOW  (ensures correct value)

Comment: Can't this also be achieved `DEFAULTing` `updated` and never specifying it in the `UPDATE`?  (No Triggers needed.)

Comment: @RickJames defaults are set on create so that works for create,  The defaulted valued won't be changed on update.  However, without triggers, either field can be overwritten.  These are often part of what is know as audit data, so you should ensure they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

i think `updated_at` Date is nullable and `created_at` is not nullable.

If above is true then you can optimize the query in this manner.
you can avoid or have to avoid `Distinct` and `UNION`

```
SELECT col1,col2,1 as Flag
FROM test
WHERE (createdate >=@FROM
    AND createdate <= @TO)
    AND (modifieddate IS NULL)

UNION ALL

SELECT col1,col2,0 as Flag
FROM test
WHERE modifieddate >=@FROM
    AND modifieddate <= @TO
```

Comment: Why did you add that `flag`? It doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: yup you are right.Suppose I will need to find exclusive record.Then it may help me recognise.Also there is no performance impact.

Answer (score -5):

The quickest solution here is to create non clustered index ([secondary index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_secondary_index)) on your date field(s) with the unique key.

Avoid using the `between` statement as it is proven to be less efficient than using `where date > x and date < y`

Still in doubt? Run your query using `TOP 100`, you'll get a result set cycle finished and be able to determine if it suits your needs.

Comment: Where's the proof that `BETWEEN` is slower than `>=` and `<=`?  The Optimizer turns one into the other.  This is a MySQL question; `TOP` does not exist.  (`LIMIT` does.)

Comment: Try it yourself, @RickJames. Not meaning to be condescendant, but certainly assuming that you marked my answer down. You have one go at it. Then, next time you will run either or, they will run at the same speed since their RS is now in memory. It'll also be quicker and less confusing on code maintenance when reading a between, you need to remember that it equals greater or equal than and smaller than.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is "inclusive".  "Inclusive" is usually wrong for `DATEs` and `DATETIMEs`.  Or it is messy to construct due to date computation, leap-years, etc.  So, I dislike `BETWEEN` for such.  Instead I prefer `>=` and `<`.

Comment: It's been more than a decade since I conclusively answered the speed debate between `BETWEEN` and operators.  There _is no difference_.  Sure caching can make the _second_ query faster than the first; I've also known that for a decade.  (Two flavors of caches can be involved in that.)

Comment: Yes, I downvoted it.  But I am slow to downvote anyone.  You had 3 paragraphs, each with something wrong.  I've explained P3 and P2.  P1 is ambiguous about how many indexes to make and what exactly to put in it/them.  (And it sounds like a non-mysql DBA -- MySQL users rarely say "create a non-clustered index".)

Comment: Feel free to make this all go away by deleting your Answer.

Comment: Non Clustered index is generic DBA terminology that dba from many systems recognizes. As far as I'm concerned, this is DBA stack exchange. Further, if you are self absorbed into the singular world of relational database that only applies to MySQL, I also included the MySQL terminology in parenthesis and even provided a link. Following StackExchange guidelines. As you mentioned, I indeed recommended using the greater than and smaller than for the comment you added. So far, 2 right out of 2. As for the third paragraph. Just. Try. It. The notable difference occurs once, at first run.

Comment: Greater than is _not_ what `BETWEEN` implements.  It is `>=`.

Comment: @WickedFan absorbed or not, the question is about MySQL, not any other product. Using `TOP` in the answer of a mysql question will not attract upvotes. Your claims that `BETWEEN` is proven to be less effiicient than using `>` is unjustified. Where is the proof? And is the claim about all DBMS? Or some specific ones? I have used MySQL, SQL Server and Postgres, I haven't seen such behaviour in any of them.

Comment: @WickedFan I tried adding `TOP 100` to a MySQL query but all I got was a syntax error and a lousy t-shirt

Comment: Perhaps this point can be derived from the many comments above, but in none of those comments it seems to me explicit enough and I fear beginners might be confused. So for their sake I would like to say it once and for all (in this comment thread at least): `x BETWEEN a AND b` is equivalent to `x >= a AND x <= b` and not to `x > a AND x < b` or `x >= a AND x < b` (or `x > a AND x <= b`, for that matter). [Proof](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=86779d294bc059a7098b0f86b47486dd). (This is just to clarify the equivalence point, not to argue about which is more appropriate and when.)